# Access node and electron modules in the isolated world

Tags: javascript, electron

I am working on chrome extensions in an electron application. As per the documentation, I want to run each content script in a separate isolated context using electrons `webFrame.executeJavaScriptInIsolatedWorld` with a specific worldId for each extension.

```
webFrame.executeJavaScriptInIsolatedWorld(1001, [
  { code }
])
```

These content scripts use chrome APIs using `window.chrome` object. For providing a chrome object to each isolated world, I need to run some script that will create a chrome object and attach to the window object. The problem here is the custom script I am using for creating the chrome object uses electron and node modules.

```
const config = ipcRenderer.sendSync(channelName, extensionId)
```

Since these modules are not available in the isolated worlds(other than 999), I am getting module not found errors for `require` and `electron`

Is there any way to access node and electron modules in isolated worlds other than 999?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12146) or [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11608) will help

Comment: Thanks Pushkin. It is working in the default electron isolated context(worldId 999). But the problem is each extension content script should be executed in a different context(other than 999).